# HTACCESS Stopped working for removing page extensions

Tags: .htaccess

I have been using htaccess for performing the following functions:

1. Redirect to https version
2. Add WWW. if the request is without www
3. Remove .php extensions from all pages
4. Add tailing slash to all pages (eg. /page/)

The code I have is using is:

```
RewriteRule ^(directory1|directory2)($|/) - [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404/

#Remove Php extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

#Add Tailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#Add WWW and https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#SEO INDEX FIX

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything used to work fine before but now after I upgraded to php 7.4 if I try to access page using .php extension its not removing .php and adding /.

Please help me correct the htaccess code..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
#Add WWW and https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#Add a trailing slash to pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
 #Remove .PHP from URLs
 #The rule bellow redirects URLs to remove .PHP (file.php =>file)
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R]
 #The rule bellow maps non PHP URLs to PHP
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a different browser to test these rules.